# when call web service, redirect to login page

Tags: web-services

hi 
i'm provide a web application and on it, i develop a web service. but when calling web service it's going to login page automatically.
i have an authentication tag on web.config file that protection property set by "All".
i want when i call web service, it should load without login and another page have this security.
please help me.

Comment: Can you post the authentication code in your `web.config` file?

Comment: @user735407, what problem are you having implementing this plan?

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in your website - "WebServices". In that folder create a web.config file in which allow anonymous access to the content i.e. Allow All.